# iOS6 ] Jump to another view before loading and showing the current view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios6

so this is how my software should run.

I have an agreement viewcontroller which will display and ask users if they agree with our policy prior to running the software. Once the users agree by pressing an 'agree' button, it will disappear and never be shown again to them.

The problem is that I have to check if they previously agreed or not before loading views and decide if the program can skip the agreement page... and I'm not sure where to do it.

viewDidLoad() is definitely not the one cuz it's literally called after a view is loaded. I tried with iniWithCoder() and no luck.  I tried with didfinishlaunchingwithoptions() but it seems like storyboard doesn't call it :(  ...

Any advice for me plz?

I will be digging in iOS Developer Library while waiting for your advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is record the fact that they clicked on the page in NSUserDefaults. From next time on check the NSUserDefaults and if it is present in that, do not show the page.

Some sample code, you can put in the App Delegate or in your view controller logic.

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"visited"]){
    NSLog(@"Second time visitor");
}else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"visited"];
    NSLog(@"First time visitor");
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Ummm that still gives me the same question - where am I supposed to prevent the agreement page from displaying? in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Is your agreement page a view controller by itself. If it is, then obviously this logic has to be put where the view controller is pushed onto a navigation controller etc. Other wise, if it is a view, then this logic can be put where you are adding that view as a subview. Without additional code as to where you are doing it, it is difficult to answer

Comment: I see the concept there :) I will give it a try.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You choose view controllers in AppDelegate.m.
Try this after you check the values you have stored in NSUserDefaults:

[Conditionally start at different places in storyboard from AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451975/conditionally-start-at-different-places-in-storyboard-from-appdelegate)