# Storyboard with differing initial view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a problem with launching different views.

I have some kind of a tutorial. Therefore I have set this code in didFinishWithLaunchOptions:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
        // Schon mal geöffnen. Kein Tutorial
    }
    else {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // Wurde das erste mal geöffnet. Tutorial anzeigen!
    }
```

But I don't really know how to make it actually open the different views now. Couldn't find any documentation on it :(

I just want to open a tutorial viewController if its the first launch and if its not the initial viewController.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *controller = nil;

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
    controller = [HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"HomeViewController" bundle: nil];
}
else {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    // Wurde das erste mal geöffnet. Tutorial anzeigen!

    controller = [TutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"TutorialViewController" bundle: nil];
}

self.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

Comment: The debugger tells me that it can't find my nibName??

Comment: If you initialize your view controller using a nib file, then you need to create one in IB and the name of the file needs to match the name you use in initWithNibName:bundle:

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451975/conditionally-start-at-different-places-in-storyboard-from-appdelegate). I modified the answer to fit your case, you should put the following code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
NSString *storyboardIdentifier;
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
    // Schon mal geöffnen. Kein Tutorial
    storyboardIdentifier = @"mainViewController";
} else {
    // Wurde das erste mal geöffnet. Tutorial anzeigen!
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    storyboardIdentifier = @"tutorialViewController";
}

UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[[self window] rootViewController] storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardIdentifier];
[[self window] setRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

For instantiating a viewcontroller from a storyboard the following will work:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

TutorialViewController *controller = (TutorialViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TutorialViewControllerID"];
```

Remember to set a ID for the viewcontroller in your storyboard.