# How to load a specific scene when application starts based on NSUserDefaults in storyboard

Tags: iphone, storyboard, nsuserdefaults, segue

I am new to storyboards. I have made up an application that has a login screen. Once the user logs in, his username and password are saved in `NSUserDefaults`. This is because when the user has to login only once after installing the application. Whenever the user opens the application again, the login page should not appear. I dont know how to achieve this in storyboards. An someone please guide me how to do this?

**EDIT:**

I have written the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"password"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"url"]) {
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationview"];
}
else {
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
}
return YES;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451975/conditionally-start-at-different-places-in-storyboard-from-appdelegate

Comment: I get the following error:
Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
See Code in Question.

Comment: Make sure that you have set a controller as 'Initial View Controller' in your storyboard (it will show an arrow pointing to the scene). After that you'll be good to go.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm gonna mark it as duplicate since the linked answer was what you're looking for.