# Trouble setting FIrst view controller which will appear on App Startup using Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, rootview

I'm setting setting FIrst view controller which will appear on my App Startup. It should appear an UIView first time as a tutorial and, from second time, another standard view.
In AppDelegate I wrote this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TabBarController.h"
#import "TutorialController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Startup"]]) {

        TabBarController * viewControllerStandard = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
        window.rootViewController = viewControllerStandard;

    } else {

        TutorialController * viewControllerFirst = [[TutorialController alloc] init];
        window.rootViewController = viewControllerFirst;
        }

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

It doesn't return any alert but, launching app, after splashscreen, it appear only a black screen. Without that codes everything works fine. What could be wrong? Thank you!

EDIT: I'm using Storyboard!

SOLVED: [Solved using followben's reply.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451975/conditionally-start-at-different-places-in-storyboard-from-appdelegate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the view controllers. For example

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TabBarController.h"
#import "TutorialController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Startup"]]) {

        TabBarController *viewControllerStandard = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
        window.rootViewController = viewControllerStandard;
        [viewControllerStandard release]; //for non-arc

    } else { 

        TutorialController * viewControllerFirst = [[TutorialController alloc] init];
        window.rootViewController = viewControllerFirst; 
        [viewControllerFirst release]; //for non-arc

    }

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: typing self.viewControllerFirst instead TutorialController * viewControllerFirst it returns this error: Property 'viewControllerFirst' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: You seem to be declaring the variable above. If you are not keeping a reference as a property of AppDelegate, then just declare the variable locally when you initialize. I've updated code above.

Comment: In both cases it appear a black screen with white bottom bar (an empty tabBar...). I modified code in question adding #import which I didn't wrote before, is it right?

Comment: Edited answer. Try that.

Comment: Sorry but probably I'm doing a very big mistake, could you tell me where I'm wrong? Sorry but I'm going crazy!! Thank you so much!! https://copy.com/lZ6LRKBhbuQn4rzN

Comment: You didn't mention you were using storyboards in your question. See here for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451975/conditionally-start-at-different-places-in-storyboard-from-appdelegate

Comment: Thank you, I didn't thought to tell that I'm using Storyboard. I'm looking that page but, actually, I haven't found a valid solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

You're not instanciating viewControllerStandard. You'll need something like this unless its been built in Interface Builder.

```
self.viewControllerStandard = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
self.viewControllerFirst = [[TutorialController alloc] init];
[self.viewController setViewControllers:@[self.viewControllerFirst] animated:NO];
window.rootViewController = self.viewControllerStandard;
```