# Reload UIStoryboard or refresh all view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, reload

Is there a way to drop current UIStoryboard and reload that one? I have a project like this. [image]

If not, is it possible to refresh all view? Purpose is I need to set all UILabel, UIButton text again.

```
lblTest.text = @"Testing";
```

Comment: Help me understand your question. You want to refresh a view, correct? Not understanding the story board part here..

Comment: It is something like I want to do like this.     self.window.rootViewController = nil;
After that, reload UIStoryboard.  Program is in App delegate, UIStoryboard is automatically called. How can I reload current UIStoryboard named MainStoryboard?

Comment: If it is not ok, I want to refresh all of my view, viewcontroller, tableviewcontroller, etc at once. How shall I do?

Comment: In which cases do you want to update UILabel, UIButton text?

Comment: I want to update when I force to change my current locale from English to chinese.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12799462/294884

or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13040627/294884

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I understand that this question isn't so much about refreshing your storyboard as it is about getting your app to be localized for English and Chinese speaking users.

Check out 'Internationalization and Localization' in the iOs Developer library. This is where you can find the resources required to turn your app into a multilingual app. They also provide a sample app called InternationalMountains, but that doesn't go into labels so much. Luckily, there are many suitable tutorials out there, like

- [Internationalization Tutorial on RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)
- [iPhone Apps localization guide on ICanLocalize.com](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

When you initially set up your controller, you should populate the labels and button text in a method that you call from viewDidLoad. When you want to "refresh" your view, to make it look like the initial condition, just call this method again. You don't need to reload the storyboard to do that.

Comment: yes. I shall do like that.However, I need to do all for all my uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uitableviewcell, etc and those will be above 50 files. I afraid I will need to write for all those. As a result, I am thinking to just drop current storyboard and reload that one.