# Displaying a view controller just if a cell wasn't already selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a root view controller. There I also have a table view. I want my user to see this root view controller only if he didn't select any cell in the past.

When the app is launched I want it to recognise if a cell was selected on that view controller. If it wasn't it will show the VC. If a cell was selected in the past, it will show another VC. The user has an option to go back to the root controller, even if a cell was already selected, but only if he wants to. I don't know how to make the app recognise this. ( I think it has to do something with the cache disk, but I can't solve this )

Comment: You could save what row was selected in NSUserDefaults, so once your application launches check to see if there is a property set with the cellIndexPath then do something with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451975/conditionally-start-at-different-places-in-storyboard-from-appdelegate

Comment: Yes, NSUserDefault is perfect, that's what i was looking for,thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need persistance data, so I see :

- **CoreData** storage, but in your case you just need some kind flag so better is
- **NSUserDefaults** [fast overview on NSUserDefaults](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/)